# OpenGl custom rotation issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to implement my custom opengl Rotation around y axix. Here is my code;

```
void mglRotateY(float angle)
{
    float radians = angle * (PI/180);

    GLfloat t[4][4] =
        {
            {cosf(angle), 0, -sinf(angle),0},
            {0,           1, 0,           0},
            {sinf(angle), 0, cosf(angle), 0},
            {0,           0, 0,           1}
        };  //Rotation matrix y

    glMultMatrixf(*t);
}
```

The effect is a rotation around y axis, but the degrees seems to not correspond.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `radians` not `angle` when calculating the sine and cosine.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you reference angle instead of radian.  Also you may want to precalc the values, as you have 4 calculations to populate the matrix `t`

perhaps something like

```
void mglRotateY(float angle)
{
    float radians = angle * (PI/180);
    float cosVal = cosf(radians);
    float sinVal = sinf(radians);

    GLfloat t[4][4] =
        {
            {cosVal, 0, -sinVal,0},
            {0,           1, 0,           0},
            {sinVal, 0, cosVal, 0},
            {0,           0, 0,           1}
        };  //Rotation matrix y

    glMultMatrixf(*t);
}
```